# Entity Framework best practices drop-down list binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

It's going to be a long one so apologies in advance. In an ASP.NET MVC application I am writing a partial control that is a search panel. Now this panel has

1. classes selection drop-down but with table instead of list (table has a checkbox, and two columns with group headers - classname and no.of students)
2. year selection as dropdownlist (hopefully the easiest of all)
3. Indicators list with checkboxes and group headers

I have defined a View model as follows

```
public class SearchControlModel
{
    public List<Class> Classes {get; set;}
    public List<Year> Years { get; set; }
    public List<Indicator> Indicators { get; set; }
 }
```

Where my entities are:

```
public class Class
{

    public int classID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> grade { get; set; }
    public string classname { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Indicator
{
    public int IndicatorID { get; set; }
    public string IndicatorDescription { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

}
```

My questions are:

1. What would be the right controls to display class and indicators (grid/table that appears as a drop-down)
2. Do I use the ado.net entities directly or through stored procedures?
3. If I use stored procedures, I will have to define a different entity that has only the specific properties that the stored procedure is dealing with or is there another way?
4. On the View (cshtml file) how do I use these properties to bind with drop-down or table e.g. something like:

   - @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Classes)
   - @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Classes, new { @class = "form-control" })

In short what is the best approach to go about it?

Here is a picture to clarify

[image]

Comment: Firstly, your view model is not correct. In order to create a `<select>` element using `DropDownListFor()`, your view model needs a property to bind to (say `int SelectedYear`) and a property for the `SelectList` (`IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`) - refer [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) for typical code)

Comment: Secondly, the `DropDownListFor()` method creates a `<select>` element, not the complex dropdown in your image, and for that you will need to create or find a custom jquery plug-in that suits your needs.

Comment: Third, you question is far too broad (and you have asked 4 of them) and opinion based.

Comment: I see jquery plug-in hmm i have a kendo license can you recommend any kendo control that suits my need and alright i got your point about select property! thanks

Comment: Asking for recommendations are off-topic :) You need to do your own research.

Comment: to create a <select> element can i do public SelectList ClassList { get; set; } inside my viewmodel

Comment: Yes, but that will just display a normal `<select>` with a list of options (not the tabular data you have shown in the image)

Comment: yes alright atleast i can use it for years dropdownlist :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using bootstrap-multiselect custom control though still wondering if it has the ability to add detail/adjacent column in it